# undeclared first use this function - compile error C++ LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a function that inserts a new node at the tail end of a linkedlist:

```
void LinkedList::insert(Node* previousPtr, Node::value_type& newData)
{
    Node *insertPtr;

    insertPtr->setData(newData);

    insertPtr->setNext(previousPtr->getNextPtr());

    previousPtr->setNext(insertPtr);
}
```

In another function I am trying to call the previous:

```
void copyData(Node* sourcePtr, Node*& headPtr, Node*& tailPtr)
{
    ...//other code
    insert(tailPtr, sourcePtr->getData());
    ...//other code
}
```

The compiler gives an error of: "insert" undeclared first use this function. What am I missing?

Comment: It's remarkable that this code _does_ use proper C++ idioms like `Container::value_type`, but still has multiple severe design issues. E.g. duplicating `std::list<T>`, and mucking round with pointers.

Comment: BTW, "first use" in the message means this is the first place where the undeclared function is called and the compiler is not going to report subsequent uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something like

```
some_linked_list->insert(some_node_ptr, ...)
```

or you could make copydata a member of the LinkedList class:

```
void LinkedList::copyData(Node* sourcePtr, Node*& headPtr, Node*& tailPtr)
```

Comment: Ah thanks I knew I was missing something :P it was the LinkedList::

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList::insert` is a method in your `LinkedList` class. You would need an instance of that class to call it.

```
LinkedList *myLinkedList = new LinkedList();
myLinkedList->insert( ... );
```